# Amazon AWS MySQL read only table

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

Is there a way to make a table in AWS RDS MySQL read only? I tried everything but it seems like I should be creating a whole replica of the db to do that. I am looking for a simpler solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a user (or modify the permissions of the current user!) so that it only has read-only access to the specific table.

Technically just grant it SELECT, not INSERT, UPDATE etc
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privilege-system.html